# Restructure the display of instantiated elements in *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, angular-ngfor

I am currently just adding randomized numbers to an array and displaying them to the user.

```
     <div *ngFor="let temp of randomIntArray; let i = index">
          <div *ngIf="i == randomIntArray.length - 1">
            This is the real random number {{ temp }}
            <div>
              <button (click)="addRandomValueIntoRandomIntArray()">
                add random number
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div *ngIf="i != randomIntArray.length - 1">
            {{ temp }}
          </div>
     </div>
```

I think I understand what's happening here as I am creating a new element on the DOM each time the user clicks : `addRandomValueIntoRandomIntArray()` as its increasing the length of the randomIntArray.

Due to the: `*ngIf="i == randomIntArray.length - 1` this will always be the last element and will be always be displayed at the bottom. Is there any feasible way for me to to swap them around and have all the new elements created at the bottom going downwards instead? Below is an image of how it currently looks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the order of ngFor items using `randomIntArray.slice().reverse()`

and you need to change `ngIf` condition to `i==0`.

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let temp of randomIntArray.slice().reverse(); let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i ==0">
    This is the real random number {{ temp }}
    <div>
      <button (click)="addRandomValueIntoRandomIntArray()">
        add random number
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="i != randomIntArray.length - 1">
    {{ temp }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have been trying to re-invent the wheel here but this seems like a practical and logical approach. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad you like it. You can upvote if it fix your issue. Thanks

Comment: Are you by any chance familiar with Angular reactive forms ? I tried to simplify my problem with the above analogy but my actual dilemma is with implementing this on a formArray

Comment: Yes you can just replace it with formarray. May be this article can help: https://www.elite-corner.com/2020/03/dynamically-adding-and-removing-form-fields-to-formarray.html